# Crear base de datos con modelos Django

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

Sucede que elimine la base de datos por unos problemas que tenia, y a la hora de querer volver a cargar mis modelos con "makemigrations" y despues "migrate", la base de datos se actualiza con los datos que django tiene por defecto, pero no me crea las tablas de mis modelos.
Cree un super usuario para acceder al sitio de administracion de Django para ver si estaban los modelos, y efectivamente están

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si doy clic en alguno como por ejemplo "citas" me aparece el siguiente error

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/hospital/cita/

(1146, "Table 'enfermeria.hospital_cita' doesn't exist")
```

y es correcto, la tabla no existe en la base de datos, por eso me gustaria saber como es que puedo volver mandar a crear las tablas en mi base de datos con base en mis modelos

PD: Como SGBD estoy usando MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Basandome en la documentacion de [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#upgrading-from-south), pude volver a cargar los modelos a la base de datos, elimine todos los archivos de la carpeta "migrations" y "**pycache**"excepto el archivo **init**, cree las migraciones y despues las cargue y listo, se crearon mis tablas en la base de datos con base en mis modelos